# IP Geo location support for IPv6

Tags: geolocation, ipv6

I wonder if someone know or working with an IP Geo location provider (commercial provider) who already support IPv6? any recommendations?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com) say they are ipv6 compatible, but I haven't verified it myself. See their [ipv6 FAQ](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ipv6).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I approached Maxmind at first, but they dont have the support yet, so I'm looking for an alternative commercial provider.

Comment: @user1587389 Do you mean that the database contains IPv6 entries, or that you access the provider's web site via IPv6? Maxmind has a perfectly functional IPv6 geolocation database and I've been using it since long before you asked this question.